# How would I populate a listview with images from drawable using a path from a database?

Tags: android, image, listview

Right now, I have a listview that is being populated with data from an existing database. It is only being populated with text but I want it to also display images. In the database, I stored the image path in the table for the corresponding image of each entry. The images are in the drawable. I'm not sure how to edit it so it also displays the images.

I did this `imageview.setImageResource(getDrawable(rootView.getContext(),imagePath));` to set the image in a different activity so I figured it would be similar but I'm not sure.

```
    private void displayListView() {

        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecipes();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                //DBHandler.COLUMN_CODE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_NAME,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_TYPE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_INGRED,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_SPECIAL
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                //R.id.code,
                R.id.name,
                R.id.type,
                R.id.ingredient,
                R.id.special
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.recipeinfo,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
      }

    public static int getDrawable(Context context, String name)
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
        Assert.assertNotNull(name);

        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
```

recipeinfo.xml (format for each element in the listview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:id="@+id/recipe_layout">
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="4"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/special"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: `In the database, I stored the image path in the table for the corresponding image of each entry` How does such a path look like for an image in drawable?

Comment: its just a string that matches the name of the file. For example: `createRecipe("Honey Glazed Salmon”,...,"honeyglazedsalmon");`
the name of image is "honeyglazedsalmon"

Comment: Now what is the problem?

Comment: I want to display the image from the image path in the listview

Comment: That is what you want. But what is the problem? Well setImageResource will do it.

Comment: Well i guess the problem is that I'm not sure where I should put the setImageResource and how to find the imageview

Comment: That has to be done in the getView method of the listview or gridview adapter. Define your own adapter for that. Google for getview and adapter and you will find many examples.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I created a custom adapter and got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just made a custom adapter like greenapps suggested.

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recipeinfo, parent, false);
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
        TextView ingredient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ingredient);
        TextView special = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.special);
        // Extract properties from cursor
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imgpath"));
        String recipeName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String recipeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
        String recipeMainIngredient = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ingred"));
        String recipeSpecial = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("special"));
        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        image.setImageResource(getDrawable(view.getContext(), imagePath));
        name.setText(recipeName);
        type.setText(recipeType);
        ingredient.setText(recipeMainIngredient);
        special.setText(recipeSpecial);
    }
}
```